# Using the cairo lib inside a gimp plugin

Tags: plugins, cairo, gimp

When writing a plugin for gimp, is it possible to use the cairo library to draw some shapes. I saw there is a function like

```
cairo_surface_t* s= ::cairo_image_surface_create_for_data (
                _rgn->data,
                 CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,
                 _rgn->w,
                 _rgn->h,
                 _rgn->rowstride
                 );
```

but I was not able to use it inside a 'common' tile loop :

```
  (...)
  /* substitute pixel vales */
  gimp_pixel_rgn_init (&src_rgn, drawable,
               x1, y1, (x2 - x1), (y2 - y1), FALSE, FALSE);
  gimp_pixel_rgn_init (&dest_rgn, drawable,
               x1, y1, (x2 - x1), (y2 - y1), TRUE, TRUE);

  for (pr = gimp_pixel_rgns_register (2, &src_rgn, &dest_rgn);
       pr != NULL;
       pr = gimp_pixel_rgns_process (pr))
    {
    (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, got it, I tested my plugin with a **non-alpha** image while I choose CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32 : the rowstride was wrong.